# Prove the product rule using the chain rule

Tags: multivariable-calculus

> **Question:**
> Prove the productrule $(fg)'(x) = f'(x)g(x) +f(x)g'(x)$,
> for functions $f,g: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ by applying the chain rule on the image $(f,g): \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{2}$ and the function $F: \mathbb{R}^{2} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined by $F(x_{1},x_{2}) = x_{1}x_{2}$

**Attempt**

$F(f,g) = fg$ (1)
$$
\frac{\partial F}{\partial f} = g  \text{ and  } \frac{\partial F}{\partial g} = f, \text{combining these together gives} \rightarrow (g,f)
$$

Looking back at (1) gives us $(f,g)$, derivative of this is $(f',g')$. Now applying the chain rule gives

$$
(g,f) \circ (f',g') = gf' + fg'
$$

I would like to know if this is correct and if not please give me corrections.

Comment: The process is correct but the notations are loose. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_rule#Multivariable_chain_rule

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\newcommand{\d}{\mathrm{d}}$Indeed, the notation is very loose. I dislike seeing $\partial F/\partial g$, for example, since $g$ is a function, a distinguished object, and not a letter denoting one of the inputs to the function $F$.

Rather, $\partial_1F(x_1,x_2)=x_2$ and $\partial_2 F(x_1,x_2)=x_1$. So the differential $\d F$ has standard matrix representation: $$\forall u,v\in\Bbb R:\,\,\d F(u,v)\simeq\begin{bmatrix}v&u\end{bmatrix}$$

If $G$ is the pairing $\Bbb R\ni x\mapsto(f(x), g(x))\in\Bbb R^2$ then it’s easy to compute the following standard matrix representation for $\d G$: $$\forall x\in\Bbb R:\,\,\d G(x)\simeq\begin{bmatrix}f’(x)\\g’(x)\end{bmatrix}$$

The map $h:x\mapsto f(x)g(x)$ equals the composite $F\circ G$. The chain rule tells you: $$\begin{align}\forall x\in\Bbb R:\,\,\d h(x)&=\d F(G(x))\circ\d G(x)\\&\simeq\begin{bmatrix}g(x)&f(x)\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}f’(x)\\g’(x)\end{bmatrix}\\&=\begin{bmatrix}f’(x)g(x)+f(x)g’(x)\end{bmatrix}\end{align}$$

Which is the same thing as saying $h’(x)\equiv f’(x)g(x)+g’(x)f(x)$, as expected.